What can be DKIM key used for?
The documentation for opendkim-genkey mentions existence of -r switch:

Restricts the key for use in e-mail signing only. The default is to allow the key to be used for any service.

I would like to know if this means that the key can be used in practice for something else than signing mails. And also if there are any reasons for including or not including the -r switch when generating the key.


What can be DKIM key used for?

Whatever you want. Note that the email service type has a much more specific meaning, the tlsrpt service type also concerns emails, but is distinguished through that value. So even strictly within the email space different usages exist.

any reasons for including or not including the -r switch

Only in the unusual case where you wish to publish and use keys under the same domain that are restricted to a non-standard service type. Then it makes sense to disambiguate that all other keys are exclusively to be understood in the typical "claiming responsibility for an introduction of a message into the mail stream" sense. Whereas their default would be to match  every service type - including your custom one.
The relevant Internet Standard section is: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376#section-3.6.1

s= Service Type (plain-text; OPTIONAL; default is "*").  A colon-
   separated list of service types to which this record applies.
   Verifiers for a given service type MUST ignore this record if the
   appropriate type is not listed.


(The opendkim-genkey utility has that --restrict flag merely to output an extra s=email; to the generated record, you could just as well add or remove that yourself from the textual record value.)
Most environments will not need this. Because their use case can be adequately served by just adding multiple signatures referencing different Signing Domain Identifier (SDID), yet sticking with the default service type.

Thank you, that's a nice answer. Is there a list of service types for DKIM? I can't find any other service types than the ones you mentioned.

@Jiří I don't think there are any other ones in use, at least not beyond the scope of individual organizations. (The mention of "IANA registry" in RFCs usually means you want to look at https://www.iana.org/assignments/ to find the values of added elsewhere. Not much there, in this case.)
